# PL/SQL Transforming Object Type to XML Date is not ISO8601

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, iso8601

I have a problem with the format of date when I transform from an Object to XML, because is not ISO8601

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE APPS.MYOBJECT IS OBJECT (
MYDATE_1    DATE,
MYDATE_2    DATE);



DECLARE
  v_myobject MYOBJECT;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   v_myobject:=new MYOBJECT(SYSDATE,SYSDATE);
   v_xml:=XMLTYPE(v_myobject);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('XML='||v_xml.getstringval);
END;
```

The output of this is:

```
XML=<MYOBJECT><MYDATE_1>19-MAR-15</MYDATE_1><MYDATE_2>19-MAR-15</MYDATE_2></MYOBJECT>
```

and I want the Date on format ISO8601, like this:

```
XML=<MYOBJECT><MYDATE_1>2015-02-19T15:16:00Z</MYDATE_1><MYDATE_2>2015-02-19T15:16:00Z</MYDATE_2></MYOBJECT>
```

Is there any way I can specify the format of the transformation of the data type DATE???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal, but as a workaround you can change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  v_myobject MYOBJECT;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   v_myobject:=new MYOBJECT(SYSDATE,SYSDATE);
   v_xml:=XMLTYPE(v_myobject);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('XML='||v_xml.getstringval);
END;
/

Session altered.
anonymous block completed
XML=<MYOBJECT><MYDATE_1>2015-03-19 18:42:23</MYDATE_1><MYDATE_2>2015-03-19 18:42:23</MYDATE_2></MYOBJECT>
```

You can include the fixed T and Z if you need those, by using this instead:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"';
```

Or `dbms_xmlquery` [seems to handle dates closer to what you expect](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2416433), so you could do this:

```
-- just to check we are not just picking up the previous value!
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
DECLARE
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
  v_ctx dbms_xmlquery.ctxhandle;
BEGIN
   v_ctx := dbms_xmlquery.newcontext('select MYOBJECT(SYSDATE,SYSDATE) MYOBJECT from dual');
   dbms_xmlquery.setrowtag(v_ctx, null);
   dbms_xmlquery.setrowsettag(v_ctx, null);
   v_xml := XMLTYPE(dbms_xmlquery.getxml(v_ctx));
   dbms_xmlquery.closecontext (v_ctx);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('XML='||v_xml.getstringval);
END;
/

Session altered.
anonymous block completed
XML=<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<MYOBJECT>
   <MYDATE_1>2015-03-19 19:07:41</MYDATE_1>
   <MYDATE_2>2015-03-19 19:07:41</MYDATE_2>
</MYOBJECT>
```

But that assumes you don't need the object to be available for anything else within the block. And doesn't have the T and Z if those are important.

Comment: I'm not familiar with objects in PL/SQL, but wouldn't a `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'format goes here')` work as well?

Comment: @Mr.Llama - the object field datatype is `date` though, at least in this example. Using a string field instead might work but depends what else the object type is used for. And not sure if you can change the default 'to string' behaviour of the object; I can't see how but I don't use objects much so I may be missing something. You could build the XMLType up from elements based on the object fields manually, I suppose, but that's more work too.

Comment: Thanks with  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"''';    works OK